# disable snd_hda_intel power save

Tags: drivers, sound

I know this question is all around with many suggested solutions, but they do not seem to work for me.
I am using Ubuntu 22.04, and have a dual boot system. One is desktop, and the other is Ubuntu studio.
On both OS's, I have a constant high pitched tone in the audio. It is very annoying in the monitor speakers, and I am also worrying that it will get into my recordings.

In ununtu 20, I traced this to snd_hda_intel power_save being enabled.
So in 22.04, I changed /sys/module/snd_hda_intel/parameters/power_save to 0, and
/sys/module/snd_hda_intel/parameters/power_saveController to N.
This worked temporarily after a reboot, but then something set it back to ON again, and the high whine came back.
When I looked at the two files again (in 22.04) they had been set back to power save ON.
can anyone tell me how to fix this? I have no need for power_save on a desktop, but I do need clean audio.
Thanks for any help,
Frustrated bob

Comment: You were using Ubuntu Core 20 before? That is the only version of Ubuntu using a single digit version number. From your question "One is desktop, and the other is Ubuntu studio." What does this mane? I do not understand what one is desktop means, please clarify.

Comment: It was 20.04, sorry for the minor rev omission. I overlooked it. There were also some updates so it had a dot revision after the .04

Answer (score 1):

To disable `power_save` permanently run

```
sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/snd-hda-intel.conf <<< "options snd_hda_intel power_save=0"
```

Reboot to apply.

Changing something is `/sys/...` is reverted on reboot.

Comment: Thanks very much, I will do that.....Bob

Comment: Hello Again, sorry to bring up the same issue, but disabling snd_hda_intel power_save only worked to Quiet the output audio on ubuntu desktop 22.04. when I activate the input channel, the high tone comes back. when I do cat /sys/module/snd_hda_intel/parameters/power_save, It returns 0 (OFF). Tile file "power_save_controller" is set to N in the same subdirectory. 
I should mention that I am using two USB audio interfaces and all of the HD and HDMI audio devices are set to OFF. Am I missing something about controlling the USB devices?....Thanks, Bob